# ¿ Como pasar datos de una clase a otra en javascript usando addEventListener o patron observador?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Tengo una pagina web de un formulario en el que tengo unos componentes colocados con Bootstrap.

Tengo un componente que es una barra que a medida que voy rellenando las preguntas de un formulario la barra debe ir creciendo. Para eso tengo una clase hecha que se llama barra y otra que se llama formulario. La clase barra debe recoger el numero de preguntas que se van contestando de formulario.

El formulario manda un evento a la pagina principal con:

```
window.parent.postMessage
```

Y lo recojo con:

```
window.addEventListener ('message', function(e) { // código  });
```

¿ Es correcta esta manera de pasar datos de una clase a otra ? ¿ Hay alguna mas sencilla ? He leído que se puede hacer con el patrón observador, pero no se como se implementa en javascript

Voy a agregar mas codigo para aclararlo:

En lo que es la pagina principal 'pagina.html' donde tengo el formulario tengo algo asi:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    switch (e.data.tipo) {
      case "FormularioControl":
        barra.goStep(e.data.subTab);
      break;
    }
  });
```

Donde barra y formulario es un objeto de una clase en javascript que lo instancio como

```
var  barra = new BarraControl();
var formulario = new FormularioControl();
```

Dentro de la clase FormularioControl tengo una llamada a un metodo cada vez que se pulsa boton de siguiente y que manda un mensaje a pagina principal.html de esta manera:

```
window.parent.postMessage({"tipo":"FormularioControl", "subTab": this.currentSubTab }, "*");
```

Donde la llave 'tipo' refleja de que clase viene el mensaje, en este caso de "FormularioControl" y la variable "subTab" tiene el valor del paso por el que va. Segun este valor la barra crecera o decrecera.

Comment: Mensajes entre páginas o entre clases?

Comment: Entre clases ( objetos ) que están en esa página. En este caso sería como componentes de la pagina que se envían mensajes

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que tienes para la clase que controla el formulario? Generalmente se pide un [mcve] exponiendo el problema

Comment: Ok , probare a ver de resumirlo es que tengo un codigo muy largo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente lo que estás haciendo es usar la mensajería para implementar el patrón [Observador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)), que no es más que permitir a otros componentes saber los cambios en una clase *Observable*.

Si quieres hacerlo sin usar los eventos del API de mensajería, que están más pensados para la comunicación entre páginas distintas abiertas en el mismo navegador, podrías implementarlo tú con algo como:

```js
class FormularioControl {

  constructor() {
    this.observadores = [];
    console.log('Empezamos con', this.observadores.length, 'observadores');
  }
  //... métodos con el código de control del formulario
 
  subscribe(callbackFn) {
    if (typeof callbackFn === 'function') {
    console.log('Añadimos una subscripción');
      this.observadores.push(callbackFn);
    }
  }
  
  notificarObservadores(datos) {
  console.log('Nofiticamos a todos');
    this.observadores.forEach( callbackFn => callbackFn(datos));
  }
  
  simularAvance() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.notificarObservadores({progreso: i*25})
      }, 1500 * i);
    }
  }
  
}

class BarraControl {

  constructor (id) {
    this.progreso = 0;
    this.barra = document.getElementById(id);
  }
  
  actualizarProgreso (p) {
    this.progreso = p;
    this.barra.value = +this.progreso;
    console.log('Progreso Actual:', this.progreso);
    
  }
}

const formulario = new FormularioControl();
const barra = new BarraControl('progreso');
const barra2 = new BarraControl('progreso2');
formulario.subscribe(datos=> barra.actualizarProgreso(datos.progreso));
formulario.subscribe(datos=> barra2.actualizarProgreso(datos.progreso));
formulario.simularAvance();
```

```html
<progress id="progreso" value="0" max="100">
</progress>

<progress id="progreso2" value="0" max="200">
</progress>
```

Comment: Excelente solución ! Muchas gracias !

Comment: Tengo una pequeña duda en este codigo, en el caso que desee desubscribirme ?

Comment: Pablo es posible que el objeto barra a su vez tenga un método subscribe para notificar a formulario ? Lo he probado y parece que no funciona en este caso.

Comment: La barra tendría que ser un observable, en ese caso

Comment: Por otro lado no pensé en desuscripciones, pero podría hacerse que al suscribirte la función devolviese un ID, de manera similar a `setTimeout` o `setInterval`

Comment: Pablo me refiero a subscribirse barra en formulario y además formulario en barra para que barra mande otra notificación a formulario. Tengo algún problema con esto porque parece que no funciona.

Comment: Crea otra pregunta con lo que tienes, va a ser más fácil

Comment: Ok, lo volveré a revisar y sino volveré a crear la pregunta.

Comment: Pablo funciona perfectamente, tenia un pequeño error en mi código. Gracias por contestar.